# SplideJS full-width images slider not autoplaying

Tags: javascript, css, splidejs

I'm using Splide as a full-width slider on a page with images taken from a loop of my database:

```
<div class="splide b-bottom-accent is-hidden-mobile">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
      @foreach($slider_images as $image)
      <div class="splide__slide"><img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->path) }}"></div>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

my javascript to trigger the slider:

```
new Splide( '.splide', { 
  type  : 'fade',
  perPage: 1,
  gap: 0,
  padding: 0,
  rewind: false,
  width : '100vw',
  height: 390,
  cover: true,
} ).mount();
```

The `cover` option makes it so the images become background of the div and can be cover, the `perPage`, `gap` and `padding` options are there to make the fade work.

The documentation doesn't say how to activate autoplay, I think it implies is automatically activated, instead, it says how to add a progressbar only :

```
You can add a progress bar or play/pause buttons for autoplay by writing a few extra lines of HTML.
```

Am I missing something? Everything works, the slider shows, the images show, the fade happens when clicking the arrows, I have no errors in my console. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add autoplay: true, and an interval is also configurable (ms). I found setting the type to fade it was best to have rewind set to true too.

```
new Splide( '.splide', { 
  type  : 'fade',
  perPage: 1,
  gap: 0,
  padding: 0,
  rewind: false,
  width : '100vw',
  height: 390,
  cover: true,
  autoplay: true,
  interval: 4000
} ).mount();
```